# Can you link several machines with FreeDOS to a Windows 2000 server on a LAN?

Tags: windows-server-2000

Have you installed / used [FreeDOS](http://freedos.org) on a server environment? Can you link them to a Windows 2000 server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you'll need network adapter drivers, an IP stack and the 'Workgroup Add-on for MS-DOS' from [THIS](http://www.freedos.org/freedos/news/technote/157.html) page.
2. Why?
3. Really, why?

Comment: I was finding this out for someone else... I wonder why myself :P

Answer (score 0):

That depends if you can find the needed drivers for your network interface card and I'd guess that you need an implementation of TCP/IP networking or some other networking protocolls supported by Windows 2000 (TokenRing, IPX/SPX, etc.). You need to explain what you mean by ``link them to Windows 2000''. If